# Solutions to $n^2\equiv1 \mod a$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was wondering if anyone had a simple way of finding the solutions to

$$n^2\equiv1 \mod a.$$

I think I read somewhere that the solutions are always

$$n\equiv\pm1 \mod a,$$

but the proof seemed inaccessible to me. Thanks!

Comment: is a composite, prime, square ?

Comment: Hint: We can write the congruence as $n^2-1 \equiv (n+1) (n-1) \equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ a)$

Comment: If $a$ is not prime, there may be more solutions. Try looking for the solutions if $a=8$. Note also that $6^2\equiv 1\pmod {35}$.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem can help you here